# CakePHP Wont Load on Localhost

Tags: php, cakephp, localhost, intl

I'm trying to load a CakePHP project from a localhost server. I'm using PHP5.6.

This is the error I keep receiving:

Error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found
File /Library/WebServer/Documents/wapapp/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Type/DateTimeType.php
Line: 269

I have installed intl extension via pecl. If I run php -m in the terminal it lists intl as installed. However, if I load localhost with a file with phpinfo() then intl is not listed. I'm not sure if intl is correctly installed although I think it is.

I have also followed the advice to uncomment this line in php.ini: extension=php_intl.dll but still no luck.

I tried XAMP as a solution but I ran into other problems (MySQL would not work).

Any help, advice or criticism appreciated. I have been banging my head against this for daaaays.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uncommenting

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

in your php.ini file? remove the ";" semicolon if you haven't.

Hope that helps

Comment: yep i uncommented that

i resolved the issue by trying again with xampp and sorting out the mysql problems

Comment: @LudovicNoble Good to know that your problem is solved :D